# Show Action's Toast in a custom view

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I needed to create a custom view to set an extra Action in a Sherlock ActionBar. Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the code:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                    | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

ActionBar actionbar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();

actionbar.setCustomView(getSherlockActivity().getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.top_sample_detail, null), lp);
actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

I can easily find the `edit` button by targeting `actionbar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.edit)`, but that's not the problem. I'd like to know if there's a default, automatic way to show the button's name in a Toast after a long click, just as it'd do if it was an Action in a non custom view.

### tl;dr

To sum up: **Is there an attribute/method/property you can set to an `ImageButton`, to make it behave as an Action item and show a `Toast` on long click, just the same ways an Action item would do?**

Comment: So all you want to do is make the `Toast` show up at a specific location?

Comment: Well... I'd like to make no difference to a regular Action. That means it should not appear when the ActionBar is on a wide screen. My question is if there's a way to show this special `Toast` when needed. I already came to a solution, but it's not perfect (and is always shown as well)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. Sum it up in one sentence.

Comment: Well, it's a long sentence, but anyway... check my edit

Comment: And what part of that is making you troubles? If I understand correctly, the `ImageButton` is already added to the ActionBar and shows up. For the Long-press, you can add a `LongPressListener`. To change the location of a Toast, use it's `setGravity()`-method.

Comment: the key is _just the same ways an Action item would do_. On wide screens, Action Items behave differently (they just don't show the Toast and show a label). In fact, I did the same you said a while ago, but it was not enough, and I thought there would be a way to skip all the low level customisations.

Comment: Since you want to add an `ImageButton`, you know about the `MenuItem.setIcon()`-method, don't you?

Comment: Even in a custom view, inflated apart and set to the actionbar with `setCustomView()`?

Comment: The idea was that you don't even need to do that. If it's only about getting your icon in the ActionBar, then this is the simplest way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27721/discussion-between-korcholis-and-lukas-knuth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've come up with a similar problem ([**here's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595248/how-to-add-a-clickable-events-action-item-to-actionbarsherlock?noredirect=1#comment30926971_20595248) the post about it) , and I have thought of 2 possible solutions:

1. extend ActionMenuItemView somehow, and make its layout to include what it needs but disable the views from showing. add your own layout to it layout. this is quite a messy solution.
2. use setOnLongClickListener on the view of the action item, and call the same code that is called for ActionMenuItemView::onLongClick . this is actually what i've written on the post i've created ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20658848/878126))

Comment: Oh gosh, after a long time I noticed I didn't accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all of that, I think you can add the item to your menu xml and set showAsAction to "always".

Comment: It's a custom view. I already have a menu, which is shown split, below the screen. I needed a button on the top actionbar.

Comment: "I needed to create a custom view to set an extra Action in a Sherlock ActionBar." I'm suggesting you don't need a custom view. If it were in your menu with the other action items, it would behave like they do and pop up a toast when long-pressed. Are absolutely stuck with using a custom view?

Comment: Well, the Activity is using a splitActionBar. Because of that, on narrow layouts the actionbar goes to the bottom, and the top actionbar just holds the title and the home button.

Comment: I see. Well, here's the code for how the action items show the toast. Maybe you can incorporate it into your app somehow. https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#L249