# How to add a clickable "events" action item to actionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, notifications, actionbarsherlock, android-custom-view

### Background

many apps (including [**google plus**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) and [**facebook**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana)) have an action bar item showing the number of in-app-events (or "notifications").

This action item has a number within it and you can click it in order to show the events the app has for the user.

something like that (taken from [**here**](https://lh3.ggpht.com/vHPn_5FJEUOrXCyLC2_zQfNioSP9iL64V8c2b9LRiYK5nd2iOaaLRCEIZ4Qs5BuN8VM=h900-rw)) :

[image]

### The problem

I wish to make it work on old android versions, so i use actionBarSherlock.

Sadly, each solution i use has its disadvantages, and i couldn't find any solution here (on stackOverflow) that handles this with actionBarSherlock (found other solutions, but not with this library).

I've also found a post about it ([**here**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/32)) , claiming it's an issue on this library, but it's very old and seems to be closed and marked as fixed, but I can't find out how to use it now.

### What I've tried

i've tried the next solutions:

- actionLayout . it showed fine, but clicking on it didn't show the clicking effect.
- actionViewClass - it didn't even work for some reason.
- adding the menu item and its view programmatically.

### The question

What's the best way to achieve this ?

---

EDIT: this is what i've tried using actionLayout :

"action_item_notification.xml" - for now it's the same as "abs__action_menu_item_layout.xml" ([**here**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/res/layout/abs__action_menu_item_layout.xml)). later i will add a textView to hold the number of notifications.

in the menu xml file, i have this as one of the items:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/activity_main__menuItem_notifications"
android:actionLayout="@layout/action_item_notification"
android:icon="@drawable/notification_button"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/notifications"/>
```

not only it doesn't show the icon, but long clicking on the item will crash the app, with a NPE on the ActionMenuItemView.java file.

---

EDIT:ok, so i've found a solution that is almost perfect.

it shows the action item nicely and it even reacts to clicking as the other action items.

I've sadly had one missing feature - long clicking on action item to show the toast of its title. sadly, i couldn't find a way to overcome this so what i did  (that works) is handling the long clicking on the view itself, and call a similar code that is used for **ActionMenuItemView::onLongClick** .

if anyone has a better and nicer solution, please write it down.

i've written this solution in a new answer here.

Comment: "actionLayout . it showed fine, but clicking on it didn't show the clicking effect" -- and what was your layout? "actionViewClass - it didn't even work for some reason" -- what does "didn't even work" mean? "What's the best way to achieve this ?" -- I'd use an `actionLayout`, with the contents set to match what ABS usually uses (probably an `ImageButton` of some sort), perhaps wrapped in a `BadgerView`: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: my layout was a simple frameLayout, also tried imageView instead. can you please show a sample code that you believe works on older android versions too?

Comment: "my layout was a simple frameLayout, also tried imageView instead" -- since neither of those would show "the clicking effect" in an activity, I have no idea why you would expect those to show "the clicking effect" in the action bar. "can you please show a sample code" -- I have not attempted to badge something in the action bar. But the programming approach would seem straight-forward enough: do what ABS does to add an action bar item yourself, and then add the badge.

Comment: still didn't help. i'll now update my question to hold what you've suggested, including the code & xml. please try to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @CommonsWare i've edited my question. now everything seems ok, but long clicking doesn't show the toast.

Comment: Where are you registering `onLongClickListener()`, and what does that listener do?

Comment: i think i have no choice but to copy the code of showing toasts (written in ActionMenuItemView::onLongClick) and add long-clicking handling for the actionView myself. do you think it's possible to use a different, better approach?

Comment: Other than potentially subclassing what is already there, I cannot think of a better approach

Comment: @CommonsWare but it extends from LinearLayout and it has children that it expects to find inside of it. maybe i could manage to bypass everything, but this also means i do dirty work , maybe even more than here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's my solution, but it's a bit messy and calls the same code of showing a toast for the action item as the one of actionBarSherlock.

if anyone has a better, cleaner solution, please write it down.

menu file (activity_main.xml) :

```
...
<item
    android:id="@+id/activity_main__menuItem_notifications"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/notifications"/>
...
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(...){
...
getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
//
final MenuItem notificationsMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.activity_main__menuItem_notifications);
notificationsMenuItem.setActionView(R.layout.action_item_notification);
setEnableLongClickOnCustomActionItem(notificationsMenuItem,true);
...
public static void setEnableLongClickOnCustomActionItem(final MenuItem menuItem, final boolean enable) {
    final View actionView = menuItem.getActionView();
    if (actionView == null)
        return;
    final CharSequence title = menuItem.getTitle();
    if (!enable || Strings.isEmpty(title))
        actionView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
    actionView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
            final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
            final Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
            actionView.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);
            actionView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);

            final Context context = actionView.getContext();
            final int width = actionView.getWidth();
            final int height = actionView.getHeight();
            final int midy = screenPos[1] + height / 2;
            final int screenWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

            final Toast cheatSheet = Toast.makeText(context, title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            if (midy < displayFrame.height()) {
                // Show along the top; follow action buttons
                cheatSheet.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT, screenWidth - screenPos[0] - width / 2, height);
            } else {
                // Show along the bottom center
                cheatSheet.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, height);
            }
            cheatSheet.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

layout file of the action item ( action_item_notification.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:focusable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/notification_button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@drawable/action_item_notification_counter_background"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:text="88"
        android:textColor="#FFffffff"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and a nice drawable for the background of the textView ("action_item_notification_counter_background.xml") :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#FFff0000" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to solve your problem - which I also had, with my final struggle being also the toast.

So, to solve the toast problem as simply as possible, just do as follow :

```
final Menu m = menu;
final MenuItem item = m.findItem(R.id.item);
final View actionView = item.getActionView();

actionView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(CWalletOffersFragment.this.getContext(), item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, v.getRight(),v.getBottom());
                    toast.show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

The position is a bit off, but not by much (you could still tweak it with an offset if you like). I really did not want to write lines upon lines of code for something so simple, so I think this is a worthy tradeoff :) !